# asymptotic with a very degenerate stationary phase

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose $f(x_1,x_2)\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^2)$. I wonder how one may derive the asymptotic expansion of the following integral when the real paramter $\lambda\rightarrow \infty$:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb R^2}e^{i\lambda x_1x_2(x_1+x_2)}f(x_1,x_2) dx_1 dx_2.
\end{equation}
Note that the origin is the only critical point of the phase function $\phi(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2(x_1+x_2)$, but it is a very degenerate one as the Hessian matrix $\big(\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\big)$ is zero at the origin. Actually, the Milnor number that describes the singularity of $\phi$ at the origin is $4$.

[EDIT: I have found an answer for this question myself. When the phase function $\phi$ is as simple as stated above, the integral's asymptotic behavior can be written down in a clean manner. The real complexity shows up when there is some perturbation in the phase, that is, when the phase is of the form $\Phi(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2(x_1+x_2)+ax_1x_2+bx_1+cx_2$, with $a,b,c$ denoting the control parameters. In the latter case, an asymptotic $\lambda$-expansion that is uniform in $a,b,c$ is very hard to get and seems not existent in the literature yet.]

Answer (score 1):

(I am not really an expert, so it should be taken with a pinch of salt.)

One may take $f=1$ and simply compute the integral using polar coordinates. (There are minor problems with convergence, but they are irrelevant.) The result is $c|\lambda|^{-2/3}$, where $c\neq 0$ is an absolute constant which I was too lazy to compute. So, in the general case the asymptotic must be $c|\lambda|^{-2/3}f(0,0)$. 
(To actually prove this may be a piece of work, but it certainly can be done if necessary.)

[EDIT] Now I think I can help. First, I would change coordinates to make the phase function more symmetric, 
$\phi(x,y)=y^3-3x^2 y$. Then, I would make use of complex variables.  Let  $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ 
be a surface defined by $x=(\cos t-iu\sin 2t)r,\,y=(\sin t -iu\cos 2t)r$, where $u>0$ is not very big. ($u=1/2$ will do.) Here $0\le t<2\pi$ and $r>0$.

The idea is to replace the original integral with 
$$\int_{\Sigma}e^{i\lambda\phi(x,y)}f(x,y)dx\wedge dy,$$
which must have the same asymptotic. This integral is convergent 
even if $f$ is an entire function, because on this surface $\Im \phi(x,y)>0$. The asymptotic series  simply comes from the Taylor series. (To make the argument rigorous one may use a partition of unity and other standard techniques.)

Comment: The asymptotic expansion should look like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\lambda^{-\frac{2+n}{3}}$. The precise questions are i) to prove that the expansion is of such a form and ii) to provide expressions or an algorithm for the coefficients $c_n$. The leading coefficient is $c_0=3^{-\frac{1}{6}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})^2f(0,0)$, which can be computed by a different method. But it is not clear how to derive other coefficients. Thanks for sharing your thought on the problem.

Comment: When $u>0$, the smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb R^2$ may not be defined on the surface $\Sigma_u$ in $\mathbb C^2$. Nevertheless, one could replace $f$ by its Taylor polynomial $T_n(f)$ of degree $n$ and show that the contribution from the difference is a power of $\lambda^{-1}$ depending on $n$ in certain way. However, for $T_n(f)$, one still needs to argue that the asymptotic expansion of its integral on $\Sigma_u$ leads to the expansion of the integral on $\Sigma_0$ when $u\rightarrow 0$. Is this obvious? (As you are aware of, $Im(\phi)$ is no longer positive on $\Sigma_0$).

Comment: Of course, it is not THIS straightforward. The argument may go as follows. Assume that $f=F\omega$, where $F$ is entire and $\omega$ is a "cap", i.e. it has a compact support and $\omega=1$ near the origin. Then the integral of $f$ over $\Sigma_0$ is equal to the integral of $f$ over some "intermediate" surface $\Sigma'$, which coincides with $\Sigma_0$ where $\omega\neq 0$ but coincides with $\Sigma_u$ far from the origin. On the other hand, the integral of $F$ over $\Sigma_u$ is equal to the integral of $F$ over the same $\Sigma'$, because the form is holomorphic.

Comment: Then, the difference is an integral of $F(1-\omega)$ over $\Sigma'$, which is small because the function is smooth and zero near the origin.

Comment: At least, this is an answer to question ii (algorithm for the coefficients).

Comment: The choice of the intermediate surface $\Sigma^\prime$ appears to depend on $\lambda$. It's not clear (at least to me) whether this would affect the argument.

Comment: I do not see what $\Sigma'$ has to do with $\lambda$. You are free to choose any $\Sigma'$; basically, the only condition is that it must coincide with $\Sigma_0$ where $f\neq 0$. Anyway, this is just a method to prove that the asymptotic is "the same", there well may be other methods without any $\Sigma'$.

Comment: I supposed that the argument requires $fe^{\lambda \phi}$ to have the same integral on $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma^\prime$. If the requirement is only only for $f$, $\Sigma^\prime$ indeed does not depend on $\lambda$. But then how does one relate the integrals of $fe^{\lambda \phi}$ on the two surfaces?

Comment: Integrals are the same, because it is the same surface where $f\neq 0$.

Comment: It seems more reasonable now. Still, I am a bit concerned about this approach of varying the surfaces. Are you able to compute the first four terms in the asymptotic expansion? I have computed them with a different method and we may compare the results to see whether they match each other.